# How to split data monthly in R

Tags: r, split, dataset

I have a dataset corresponding to the register of buys in a store, it is something like this:

```
Date          BuyId      Price     Description    Category
2010-01-01    101028        100    ...            ...
2010-01-01    101028        100    ...            ...
2010-01-01    101028        100    ...            ...
2010-01-01    101028        100    ...            ...
...
```

The dates in the dataframe goes from 2010-01-10 to 2015-04-01 and I would like to split it monthly so I can plot the volume of buys per month in each year, I mean something like:

```
Date        Count
2010-Jan    19128
2010-Feb    1232
...
...
2015-Mar    28363
2015-Apr    12834
```

I've been having a hard time with this specially because I'm pretty new to R and I don't know so many functions.

I tried to split the data using `split` but I couldn't make it. Does anyone have a clue how can I do this?

Comment: Try `split(yourdata$Value, format(yourdata$Date, '%Y-%b'))`  If this to make a summary, you can use `aggregate`, `dplyr` or `data.table` methods

Comment: Besides `format.Date` there is also `cut.Date` which provides even more facilities for aggregating date information by various intervals. See `?cut.Date`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` for this:

```
df %>%
  mutate(new.date = cut.Date(as.Date(Date, format = '%Y-%m-%d'), "month")) %>%
  group_by(new.date) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

`mutate` will create a new column with cutted dates, `group_by` by month and `summarise` will count the number of entries.

---

Also, if you need year and abbreviation month, just add one more `mutate`:

```
 %>%
mutate(new.date = format(as.Date(new.date), "%Y-%b"))
```