# How to bin date by month

Tags: r, date, binning

I have the following data:

```
  df <- data.frame(dt1 = c("2019-05-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-06-02"), 
                   dt2 =   c("2019-08-30", "2019-04-24", "2019-12-06") )
> df
         dt1        dt2
1 2019-05-02 2019-08-30
2 2019-01-02 2019-04-24
3 2019-06-02 2019-12-06
```

Here is what I want to do:

i) I want create factors by binning, for example, for the first date, the dates binned as 2019-07-31, 2019-06-30, 2019-05-31, so essentially binning by dt2.
ii) I want to count the total number of dates in each bin.

The expected output is:

```
        dt1        dt2      val_count
1 2019-05-02 2019-08-30         3
2 2019-01-02 2019-04-24         3 
3 2019-06-02 2019-12-06         6
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533500/how-to-split-data-monthly-in-r) relevant.

Note: I do not want take difference between months of two dates.

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty messy but if you want to count how many last date of the months are in between `dt1` and `dt2`, you may try

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

fd <- paste0(lubridate::year(min(df$dt1, df$dt2)), "-02-01") %>% as.Date()

ld <- paste0(lubridate::year(max(df$dt1, df$dt2))+1, "-01-01") %>% as.Date()
x <- seq.Date(fd, ld, by = "month") - 1
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(val_count = length(x[dt1 < x & x < dt2]))

  dt1        dt2        val_count
  <chr>      <chr>          <int>
1 2019-05-02 2019-08-30         3
2 2019-01-02 2019-04-24         3
3 2019-06-02 2019-12-06         6
```

Choice of `<` or `<=` depends on your purpose.

To get total days between `dt1` and `dt2`,

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(val_count = length(x[dt1 < x & x < dt2])) %>%
  mutate(dd = as.Date(dt2) - as.Date(dt1))

  dt1        dt2        val_count dd      
  <chr>      <chr>          <int> <drtn>  
1 2019-05-02 2019-08-30         3 120 days
2 2019-01-02 2019-04-24         3 112 days
3 2019-06-02 2019-12-06         6 187 days
```

## Add

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(val_count = length(x[dt1 < x & x < dt2]),
         val_count = ifelse(val_count == 0, 1, val_count)) %>%
  mutate(dd = as.Date(dt2) - as.Date(dt1))

  dt1        dt2        val_count dd      
  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <drtn>  
1 2019-05-02 2019-08-30         3 120 days
2 2019-01-02 2019-04-24         3 112 days
3 2019-06-02 2019-12-06         6 187 days
4 2019-06-01 2019-06-02         1   1 days
```

Comment: thank you for nice solution, your the code works well. I wonder if its possible to add a quick fix for the case when date is between  `2019-06-02` and `2019-06-03` to avoid outputting zeros?

Comment: @Vendetta I'm sorry. I cannot understand what you want is...Would you explain more about that?

Comment: For example, with this data `df <- data.frame(dt1 = c("2019-05-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-06-02", "2019-06-01"), dt2 =   c("2019-08-30", "2019-04-24", "2019-12-06", "2019-06-02") )`,  I get last row val_count as zero. I would like to output 1 and not zero.

Comment: @Vendetta I add the code above. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is indeed kinda messy, it just takes a simple oneliner to do this

```
df <- data.frame(dt1 = c("2019-05-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-06-02", "2019-06-01"), dt2 =   c("2019-08-30", "2019-04-24", "2019-12-06", "2019-06-02") )

df %>%
  mutate(val_count = as.period(ymd(dt2) - ymd(dt1)) %/% months(1))

#          dt1        dt2 val_count
# 1 2019-05-02 2019-08-30         3
# 2 2019-01-02 2019-04-24         3
# 3 2019-06-02 2019-12-06         6
# 4 2019-06-01 2019-06-02         0
```